# How to reset a corrupted backuped file with Duplicity?

Tags: backup, duplicity

When a Duplicity incremental backup is interrupted, some backup files may be corrupted, and cannot be recovered later on (even if new incremental backups are done after the interrupted one).

Those corrupted files can be found using `duplicity verify`.

When this happens, how to reset the backup for only those files? (instead of doing a full backup again which is a problem with GB of data)

Answer (score 1):

try using the clean command, which is intended exactly for this purpose.

..ede/duply.net

Comment: Please could you expand on this answer a little. It may be obvious to you but to someone else searching for an answer to a similar problem it would be helpful if there was some more detail.

Comment: do you mean that after corruption, `duplicity cleanup` followed by `duplicity backup` (incremental) recovers unrecoverable files?